# Readthedocs: Is there conf.py file documentation?

Tags: read-the-docs

RTD docs are pretty good, but I'm not seeing anything regarding conf.py details. For example, I want a local doc as well, and my conf.py contains:

```
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'

# override the default css
html_context = { 'css_files': ['_static/css/theme_overrides.css', ],}

# Add relative template path.
templates_path = ['../templates']
```

That code causes the RTD build to fail on rtd.com. When I remove it, the build works.

So is there documentation on what I can/can't include in conf.py?

Comment: RTD is nothing more than a CI/CD system for your reStructured/sphinx doc project, so if you set up your own CI/CD pipeline (via anything like GitHub Actions, Azure Pipeline and others) you can use that to discover such build issues in advance. The problem was probably caused by misconfiguration as you might forget to include the file in your source code repo. Including files from parent folders can be especially harmful, as CI/CD pipeline has no way to acquire those files on a clean system. Please check in all necessary files to the same repo for simplicity.

Comment: What is the build error?

Answer (score 1):

RTD supports everything that is supported by Sphinx. If you are experiencing errors that cannot be reproduced locally, more troubleshooting is needed.

Comment: These answers are off. Read my post. I've been using Sphinx/RST for a decade and know what a conf.py file is and how to use it. However, the rtd.com build process is a black box. They do apparently consume my conf.py because they read items like the project title. If I include templates_path = ['../templates']  which I need for my local build, the rtd online build fails. So, the question is: where is the documentation on what RTD expects and can't tolerate in the conf.py file. If there isn't any such doc, then how do others deal with having a local, customized build as well.

Comment: You still didn't link to the build failure, how do you expect us to give answers that are not off?

Comment: Because I don't want an answer that fixes a specific build failure. Conf.py could have a thousand different lines and possibly hundreds of build failures. I'm looking for documentation about what RTD supports/allows in conf.py. My question is explicit.

Comment: Reworded my answer. If you still refuse to link the build error, I don't think you will get any help.

Comment: Well, I'm not asking for help for the build error. I can fix the build error simply by not including one line I used in my conf.py. But without any documentation, fixes will often be a guess. So I'll assume from the response here there is no documentation, and that what can be included in the conf.py file can only be discovered by trial and error and reading the build errors generated on the RTD server.

I don't think the answer above is true. Adding: templates_path = ['./_rtdtemplates'] kills the build, but I need it for my local build.